# Display dynamic subview inside CollectionView Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

The requirement of my app is to draw multiple highlights (currently i use UIView to highlight) on an image on each cell inside collectionview. The highlighted view needs to have a long press event on it.

i managed for highlighting part of the image using below coordinate:

```
{
  "startX": 1315,
  "startY": 522,
  "endX": 1547,
  "endY": 634
},
{
  "startX": 468,
  "startY": 485,
  "endX": 1316,
  "endY": 668
}
```

each cell had different dynamic highlight point where im currently adding the subview inside `cellForItemAt` method.

here is the example code currently used:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ImageTextCell", for: indexPath) as? ImageTextCell

    cell?.imageView.image = UIImage(named:"img\(indexPath.item)")
    let data = self.datasource[indexPath.item]

    for (i, dat) in data.enumerated() {
    
        let scaledown = 2000 / self.collectionView.layer.width
    
        let minx = dat.startX! / scaledown
        let miny = dat.startY! / scaledown
        let maxx = dat.endX! / scaledown
        let maxy = dat.endY! / scaledown
    
        let hightlightView = UIView()
        hightlightView.accessibilityLabel = "\(indexPath.item)-\(i)"
        hightlightView.frame = CGRect(x: minx, y: miny, width: maxx - minx, height: maxy - miny)
        hightlightView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#000000", alpha: 0.2)
        hightlightView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressed))
        longPressRecognizer.delegate = self
        cell?.imageView.addSubview(hightlightView)

       hightlightView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
    }

    return cell!
}
```

Below are what currently i faced

1. The highlight from the current cell will also be displayed on the other cell.
2. Long Press event not working as expected. (press not detected) where im not sure why.

**Editted**

Now i managed to add the longpress recognizer after change:

from
`cell?.imageView.addSubview(hightlightView)`

to
`cell?.addSubview(hightlightView)`

Comment: The highlight is also displayed on other cells because collectionView has reuse mechanism. You should declare highlightView as a subView of the cell's content and then toggle it.

Comment: You should not be adding subviews and gesture recognizers inside `cellForItemAt`. Cells are reused, so you end up adding them multiple times. To give you an example, though... your code shows `for (i, dat) in data.enumerated()` -- does that mean you have *multiple* long-press areas on each image?

Comment: hi @DonMag, yes each uiview added, will embed with long press gesture, when user long press on the uiview, they will given chooses either to set color to the view (highlight) or set the view to transparent (dehighlight) the uiview. Each cell have multiple uiview on the image at different coordinate. I know i should not add subview in ```cellForItemAt``` but i really dont have other idea on how to achive this. Thanks for response.

Comment: @son can you show sample on this: ```declare highlightView as a subView of the cell's content and then toggle it```. Please be noted that, the coordinate of uiviews in each cell is different.

Comment: @syafiqqaziz - *"either to set color to the view (highlight) or set the view to transparent (dehighlight)"* -- so when the image is first displayed in the cell, it will have multiple translucent (`.alpha = 0.2`) rectangles (subviews) ... each rectangle can be long-pressed, and the user will select Opaque or Clear for that subview?